# How to protect a WCF Rest service with username and password?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-rest, wcf-authentication

I'm new in WCF and I want to know how can I protect a WCF Rest service.
I have an asp.net website, only registered users can access it, the application uses a service hosted on the same IIS server, my question is, how can I restrict the use of this service, for that only registered users may use it, knowing that the service can be used by many clients (Android, iPhone, ...). what type of authentication I can use? to test the service I created a winform and I use an HttpWebRequest.
**PS: I cant use https.**
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use asp.net compatibility mode. The WCF service call will result in the same preprocessing used for ASP.NET pages, including checking the ASP.NET auth and session cookies. You will also be able to check HttpContext, including httpcontext.current.user.identity.isauthenticated. If the user is not authenticated, throw an exception or return an error code. Here is some more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx.

So if you are already using forms auth for your application, and the service should be called after a user has logged in to your application, you are set.

You can also create an authentication service. The service will allow the client to send a username / password, and will use ASP.NET authentication to authenticate the user. It will send back an auth cookie, and then you can check future service calls as above. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386582.aspx.

I believe the authentication service can called using json. See [How to Call .NET AuthenticationService from json client without ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918322/how-to-call-net-authenticationservice-from-json-client-without-asp-net).

Comment: Thank you Jappel for the quick answer, but I think when we talk about a Rest service, everything must happen via URL, right ? I'm thinking that maybe the client cannot interact with cookies.

Comment: I think a lot of people would agree with you. But requiring authorization to call a service means that you'll need to pass some sort of token along to the server. Auth data like this is really meta information for your service, and cookies provide a nice way to pass this information to the server without cluttering up your service interface. I'm sure others would disagree heartily with me, but I think it's a good compromise.

Comment: Thank you very much @Japple, your answers helped me a lot, I'll suggest to my client cookies or implementation of OAuth (or something like that).